# Having trouble using subprocess

Tags: python, ruby, django

Okay so I'm building a website in Django and I need to use an API written in Ruby. I have downloaded the API and written a ruby script. Now Im working on calling the script from Django using the subprocess POpen method. Here is what I have in my Django view:

```
def call(request):
   context = RequestContext(request)
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sendCall(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save(commit=True)
          p=subprocess.Popen("cd verboice-api-ruby/lib;ruby \"verbyTest.rb\"",shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)                              
          output, errors = p.communicate()                        
          return mainIndex(request)
    else:
        print form.errors
   else:
     form = sendCall()
   return render_to_response('main/call.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

I run the server and activate the call view. The ruby script will send a call and then it returns to the main page. But it gives me an error when it comes time to call the actual ruby script. It gives me this error:

```
OSError at /main/call/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/call/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Exception Location: /anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child, line 1308
Python Executable:  /anaconda/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/manavdutta/Downloads/savinglives',
 '/anaconda/lib/python27.zip',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
Server time:    Sun, 5 Jan 2014 16:46:38 -0600
```

What am I supposed to do to stop this error?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're using `Popen` incorrectly:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ruby', 'verbyTest.rb'], cwd='verboice-api-ruby/lib', shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```